# Avoiding typing long password repeatedly

Tags: password, administration

I have a remote linux box that I login to with ssh and chrome remote desktop. It is not super critical, mostly used for my hobby projects.

I have a pretty long password created using [diceware](https://www.rempe.us/diceware/#diceware). But it's getting tedious to type it repeatedly because in a given session I need to type it at least 4-5 times.

I have resolved this for SSH into the remote box by:

- Using ssh keys.
- Disabled entering the password when using `sudo`.

However, it's still a problem when logging in with Chrome Remote Desktop for unlocking the system.

To avoid typing this multiple times, I have tried the following:

- Anytime I have to do sysadmin work, I change the password to a three letter word so I don't have to type the long one multiple times. **Con:** Easy to forget to change it back.
- Program a macro in my mechanical keyboard that types it out. **Con:** Won't help if I'm using a laptop somewhere else.

Another option I considered was make/buy a [tiny USB dongle](https://hackaday.com/2012/03/05/usb-dongle-generates-and-enters-your-passwords-so-you-dont-have-to/) that works as a HID and types the password, but with covid, I don't have access to facilities to help me make this.

Any ideas? I can't be the only one having this problem.

EDIT: Updated question to specify that the issue has been mitigated when using ssh.

Comment: Are using SSH keys an option?

Comment: Read `man ssh-copy-id ssh-keygen ssh scp`.

Comment: @cutrightjm @waltinator - I already use ssh keys for ssh. And I've set no password for `sudo`. But I need a desktop environment so I login with chrome remote desktop to use the various UI based tools. Can't get around typing the password there.

Comment: @roaima - Thanks for calling that out, have updated my question!

Comment: Disabling password prompts for all things sudo renders sudo almost pointless. You can make sudo remember that you have authenticated for a given period of time, which might be a reasonable compromise between convenience and security.

Answer (score 2):

Use an RFID tag or a barcode scanner.

For litte money (under $10) you can buy a USB RFID card reader that acts as a HID that will enter a password when presented with a tag. Some can be adjusted to append a newline at the end.  The password will be the serial number of an RFID tag and is fixed but it has reasonable entropy.

A more flexible and more secure alternative would be a USB barcode scanner.  Again it acts as a HID but here you can print your own passwords (as barcode, easy enough as there are open source tools for it) and you have more flexibility and configurability.  A simple but reliable USB barcode reader sets you back $20 to $30.  Used devices from POS terminals are available and in my experience often "just work".

Answer (score 1):

I’d probably investigate using a password manager, such as Bitwarden (no affiliation, many other managers are available).

You can use such to synchronise passwords between devices, and when you want to use a password copy it to your clipboard.